# I am getting Bounds error() that I don't know how to fix

Tags: julia

I get the error BoundsError() the goes on to say 'in setindex! at array.jl.310 (repeats 2 times)' I am not sure why

The has already opened a file and taken the txt file converted some of strings to variables, but I am only getting the problem in this section so tried putting it in a function, but no joy

```
 function electronDensityFunction() 

 z=1
 y=1
 x=1

  for i = 1:arraySizeBy6 # As data in 6 colums in .txt file
  electronDensityString = readline(f)
  electronDensityArray = split(electronDensityString,;) # split string into array

for j = 1:6
  electronDensitytTempString  = electronDensityArray[j]
  electronDensitytTempFloat = parsefloat(Float64,electronDensitytTempString) # make string a float

  #fills z first then y then x 
    if z ==zSize
    y=y+1
    z=0
  else
    z=z+1
  end
  if y==ySize
    x=x+1
    y=0
  end
  electronDensity[x,y,z] = electronDensitytTempFloat
end
end
end

electronDensityFunction()
```

Comment: Are julia array indexes not zero-based?

Comment: @500 no, array indices start at 1. @jacques, are you preallocating the `electronDensity` array?

Answer (score 2):

Some worrying things include `split(electronDensityString,;)` (that should be `";"` I believe), but I also see that

```
if z ==zSize
  y=y+1
  z=0
else
  z=z+1
end
if y==ySize
  x=x+1
  y=0
end
electronDensity[x,y,z] = electronDensitytTempFloat
```

will regularly set indices to 0, which isn't correct. I think you might want to set those to 1 instead of 0, but without the data set (or a sample of it) we cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

[`readdlm()`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/io-network/#Base.readdlm) function do the task of reading matrix of data from a text file, the better approach is to use this function. Check [here](http://randyzwitch.com/julia-import-data/) for more details about it's use-case, then it's possible to apply [`reshape()`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/arrays/#Base.reshape) function to the resulting matrix, and create an array of desired dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. For the tip. I tried it and it works i.e it doesn't give a bounds error. In what order does reshape() work. But I think it is going column first in the reshape. My data is in horizontal order first is there a way for it to reshape that way. Many Thanks